# Removing a time (i.e. 5PM to 7PM) from a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

So, here is what I have:

```
Saturday – 9AM to 3PM This is an annual event usually held in October.
```

I want to be able to pull out the times into two cell: Start Time and End Time. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - though you may want to use LibreOffice rather than Excel here, because it allows regular expression searching, making this a lot less laborious.

In Excel - I'll break out the formulas.  Assume your value is in A1, Start time should be in B1, End time in C1:

- `=FIND("day - ",A1)+6`: Finds the number of characters in the first time is. (12)
- `=FIND(" to ",A1)`: Finds the number of characters to the end of the first time (15).
- `=MID(A1,FIND("day - ",A1)+6, FIND(" to ",A1)-FIND("day - ",A1)-6)`: Finds the start time (extracts characters 12-15, 9AM).

It's a similar process for End Time:

- `=FIND(" This", A1)`:  Find the end of the end time (23).
- `=MID(A1,FIND(" to ",A1)+4,FIND(" This",A1)-FIND(" to ",A1)-4)`: Should get you your end time!

Comment: Is there a way to generalize it? I need to do this on many other cells where they aren't all the same `day`

Comment: This approach should work for any day ending in "day".  Or am I misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: Oh okay I get it now. Well, I have different formats. They will always have the " - " before the time start but some are formatted like this: `Saturday (25th annual) – 9AM to 3PM Craft Show is an annual event held the first Saturday of November.` So it won't always have "day - "

Comment: As long as the first dash is always right before the start time, you can just cut `day -` to `- `.  Reduce the "+6" to a "+2" in that case, and same with the "-6" to "-2".

Comment: I got the start time to work, I think you had a typo in the start time formula, `D13 should be A1` but thanks a lot!

Comment: But, for this entry `Saturday (25th annual) – 9AM to 3PM Craft Show is an annual event held the first Saturday of November.` the end time isn't working. Not sure why.

Comment: Actually...I see you are looking for " This" which isn't in this one..I'll work on that. thanks again

Comment: I fixed the D13 references - I was testing my formulas in a different cell, then moved it to A1 for simplicity.

Comment: You can deal with not knowing what word comes after the end date by searching for the "to" and adding 5.  That will capture two-digit times like "10PM" correctly, but leave an extra space after "3PM ".  You can fix it with TRIM or leave as is.